# C# - InvalidCastException despite using an already working function

Tags: c#

So I'm continuing to work on my project, currently reusing a function that I have previously already worked with and that has worked perfectly too, though now it seems that it doesn't in this interation of it.

```
var c = (Customers)comboBox_Customers.SelectedItem;
newContact.Name = textBox_Contact_Name.Text.Trim();
newContact.Firstname = textbox_Contact_Firstname.Text.Trim();
newContact.FKCustomer = c.PKCustomer;

db.Contacts.Add(newContact);
db.SaveChanges();
Close();
```

The above code is the snippet that works, below is the one that doesn't.

```
var b = (TArticle)comboBox_Article.SelectedItem;
TPosition newPosition = new TPosition();


newPosition.FKArticle = b.PKArticle;
newPosition.Quantity = (int)numericUpDown_Quantity.Value;
newPosition.Position = textBox_Position.Text;
db.TPosition.Add(newPosition);
db.SaveChanges();
Close();
```

They look pretty much identical to me, apart from the fact that they are adressing different Tables in the database. The exception gets thrown at me, when he passes the declaration point of var b.

Edit:

Customers and TArticle are both database tables, the SelectedItem in the working instance is the name of a Customer, in the instance that is not working SelectedItem is the name of an Article.

I *think* I need to cast in order to get the Primary Key from the TArticle table, which I need to save into TPosition as Foreign Key.

Comment: That means that your `comboBox_Article.SelectedItem` is not a `TArticle`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. From what I can see in your code you're creating an object, then you're adding it to EF and have it persisted (saved to the database). I assume that Customers and TArticle are both entities that are mapped to database tables. Why do you need to do the cast? In the first example you're assigning an object, in the second it's a text property. It is not clear how TArticle and Customers exactly look like. Please try to describe a bit more details and what the problem is.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don´t know what `TArticle` is and what `SelectedItem` is.

Comment: Your edit is more confusing.

Comment: "in the instance that is not working SelectedItem is the name of an Article." -> if this is the case, then obv you cannot cast a string to an object of type TArticle

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota Maybe I'm just stupid but I don't see why it works in the first example in that case. The Article name is saved in a column in TArticle, just like it is with the Name in the working example.

Comment: What is the itemsource of your comboBox_Article?

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota The itemsource of comboBox_Article is TArticle.

Comment: You mean a collection of TArticle. right? Basically, the code here is not the problem, the problem may be with the way you have binded your combobox (assuming wpf)

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota I populate the comboBox straight from the Database table, which is TArticle. This is windowsforms and not WPF too. In case it is of intereste to you, this is how I populated it.

    var a = db.TArticle;
    foreach (var item in a){
                comboBox_Article.Items.Add(item.Articlename);
            }

Answer (score 0):

You should add items type of `TArticle` to your `comboBox_Article`, to be able to cast it back.

```
public class TArticle
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int FKArticle { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}

private void InitTArticleComboBox()
{
    TArticle item = new TArticle()
    {
        Text = "Article1",
        Value = 11
    };

    comboBox_Article.Items.Add(item);
    comboBox_Article.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

and then

```
var b = comboBox_Article.SelectedItem as TArticle;
TPosition newPosition = new TPosition()
{
    FKArticle = b.PKArticle, //supposed that your FKArticle is int too (well, in this particular example)
    . . .
};
```